# SharePoint Online URI not Creating new File

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to create a URL, that may be used as bookmark to create a new document in a SharePoint Online folder.

I tried it like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes), but the following URI only opens a file, but does not create a new one in the desired folder, as I expected.

`ms-excel:nft|u|https://gbst.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/Forms/EbalePy205pJlrazKKvr1qQB_wuMv_KvxOsakaWol?e=DlCPKc|s|https://gbst.sharepoint.com/:f:/s/Forms/test/`

What did I get wrong and how can I fix or improve this?